# PDFPage thumbnail (UIImage) does not respect PDFPage orientation in iOS 13 (Xcode 13.1)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ios13, ios-pdfkit

### Description

I am having issue with `UIImage` "generated" from `PDFPage` via method `.thumbnail(of:for)`. `UIImage`, which I later display in `UIImageView`, does not respect rotation of the PDF page, **in iOS 13 only**.

When PDF page is rotated for example by 90° and presented in `PDFView` all is good and shown correctly. But when I want to take the `UIImage` (i.e. thumbnail) of the `PDFPage` and show it in `UIImageView`, for some reason, iOS 13 does not respect the initial rotation of the PDF page and present it in `UIImageView` incorrectly.

**Please behold on below sample code and example screenshots.**

### Testing environment

- iOS 13 on simulator only, not having real device
- Xcode 13.1

### Sample code

*for sake of shorter example, I force unwrap where optionals occur*

```swift
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class TestingViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()
    
    // Pass URL of the PDF document when instantiating this VC
    init(withURL: URL) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: withURL)
        let pdfPage = pdfDoc!.page(at: 0) // Getting first page of the doc
        let pdfPageRect = pdfPage!.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        imageView.image = pdfPage!.thumbnail(of: pdfPageRect.size, for: .mediaBox) // Getting the UIImage of the PDF page and assign it to the needed image view
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        print("\(pdfPage?.rotation)") // Prints the correct rotation value, even though UIImageView does not respect it
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // Layout only
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700),
        ])
    }
}
```

### Example screenshots from simulator

✅ [iOS 15, shown correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4FxV.png)

❌ [iOS 13.2, shown incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCAXK.png)